# how to configure the auto-formatting in my *.svelte files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting, svelte

I am new to Svelte ( and also to frameworks in general ), I have set up a Svelte project and am trying out a few things.

But the formatting is really distracting me, currently my code gets auto-formatted into this ( Shift + Option + F ):

[image]

Is there a way for me to configure this?

I've tried:

- adding the `prettier` key to my **package.json**
- adding **settings.json** file in the **vscode** folder with the following:

```
    {
        "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    }
```

In addition to changing the tab size, I'd also like the code in the image above to auto-format to:

```
    config = Object.assign({
        mass: 1,
        stiffness: 100,
        damping: 10,
        velocity: 0
    }, config);
```

The template code are also auto-formats to this:

[image]

I think it's much easier to read if it was like this:

```
    <FadeIn
        from={{ blur: 8, scale: 0.6 }}
        config={{ stiffness: 10, damping: 20 }}
    >
        <p>Hello</p>
    </FadeIn>
```

Please help me if you know how to configure this, thanks!

Comment: Try to add editorconfig plugin and .editorconfig file also. Have you check your vscode default formatter config yet?

Comment: If you want to format your svelte file you may need vscode svelte plugin. If you want to config prettier yourself add `"[svelte]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" }` to `settings.json` and don't forget to install `prettier-plugin-svelte` and add it to configuration file also. Note: prettier plugin may conflict with eslint plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question to "put brace in same line vs put brace in next line": There was an [issue](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-php/issues/107) regarding this which has been resolved and an option 'braceStyle' has been added, [but only for PHP](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-php/commit/68347e25cfab23acf8fb5df762dd62e66304619e).

```
| `braceStyle`    | `"psr-2"` | If set to `"psr-2"`, prettier will move open brace for code blocks (classes, functions and methods) onto new line. <br> If set to `"1tbs"`, prettier will move open brace for code blocks (classes, functions and methods) onto same line. |
```

To [configure prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html), I use a .prettierrc file in my workspace where I put the [configuration](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html).

Ad @name:clitetailor's comment regarding "format svelte files": Did not know which configuration to put into which config file to make prettier-plugin-svelte working, but ended up with installing Svelte VS Code Plugin: [jamesbirtles.svelte-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JamesBirtles.svelte-vscode). It internally uses prettier-plugin-svelte, and does proper configuration of VS code. Format of svelte files worked immediately after install.

Answer (score 0):

Format single .svelte file in 'vscode' editor.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=melihaltintas.svelte-format

Keyboard Shortcuts
mac: cmd+ctrl+p
win: alt+ctrl+p